# Product of a strictly decreasing function and a concave function is quasi concave?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Consider a function $f(x) = u(x)v(x), x \in [0, \infty)$ where $u(\cdot)$ is a strictly decreasing function and $v(\cdot)$ is a concave function. We know $f(x), u(x), v(x) \geq 0, \forall x \in [0, \infty)$.

I am wondering if $f(\cdot)$ is quasi-concave.

> $f$ is a quasi-concave function if $f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) \geq \min(f(x), f(y))$ for all $\lambda \in [0, 1]$.

Since $u(x)$ is strictly decreasing, we have $u(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) \geq \min(u(x), u(y))$. Since $v(x)$ is concave, we have $v(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) \geq \lambda v(x) + (1-\lambda)v(y)$.

Then $f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) = u(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) v(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) \geq \min(\lambda u(x) v(x) + (1-\lambda)u(x)v(y), \lambda u(y) v(x) + (1-\lambda)u(y)v(y)) $. I do not know how to proceed. But intuitively, I believe it should be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counterexample:
$$u(x)=\frac1{\ln(\ln(2.8+x))},\quad v(x)=\ln(2+x).$$
$f(2)>2.7$, $f(8)<2.7$, $f(20)>2.7$